# Parent siblings not showing after hiding/showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple in-page search function which shows only topics which contain words searched for.

Each section has a heading, a `<h2>` - I want the headings for the blocks which are not hidden, to show.

**The problem:** The `h2` header does not always show after the search

[This is a fiddle to test the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/L0m3z98y/)

**Fail/success examples:**

One of the headings is `Complaints and cancellations` - sub section titled: `How do I cancel`

If you search for `how do` then you'll see the first block show, with header... the second block titled `Guides` disappears. This is correct.

If you search for `I cancel` - again, the second block disappears, which is correct, but, the heading for the first block hides too, which it shouldn't.

This is the javascript:

```
$("#faq_search").on("input", function () {
        var v = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".vc_tta-panel").each(function () {
            var eachPlace = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
            if (v != "" && eachPlace.search(v) == -1) {
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings('h2').hide();
                $(this).fadeOut();

            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn('fast', function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings('h2').show();   
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `hide` of the `h2` can occur *after* a `show` for the same section, *depending on the order of matches* in the section.

The quick solution is to do all the hides first, then the shows:

```
$("#faq_search").on("input", function () {
    var v = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".vc_tta-panel").each(function () {
        var eachPlace = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        if (v != "" && eachPlace.search(v) == -1) {
            $(this).closest('.vc_tta').siblings('h2').hide();
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $(".vc_tta-panel").each(function () {
        var eachPlace = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        if (v == "" || eachPlace.search(v) > -1) {
            $(this).fadeIn('fast', function(){
                $(this).closest('.vc_tta').siblings('h2').show();   
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/L0m3z98y/2/

### Notes:

- `parent().parent().parent()` is a not a maintainable solution. Any change to the DOM structure will break the code. Instead use `closest()` with an appropriate target selector. This is shorter and safer